# Dismiss UIPopOverScreen when touching NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I have this UIPopOverScreen that shows when I press a NavigationBar Button.
The problem I want to dismiss it whenever I touch anything outside that popoverscreen.
It partly works but it doesn't dismiss when touching the navigationbar which has been built into the VC that calls the popoverscreen.

I've tried several options to make it disappear but it just hasn't worked yet.
The best results I've gotten when I set:

```
self.popOverController.passthroughViews = nil;
```

It worked as I wanted but by just setting this you have to press the navigationbar twice to make it respond again.

I would love to hear your thoughts about a clean solution.

Comment: strange. I had the same issue, and setting the passthroughViews to nil immediately after presenting the popover works perfectly for me. I don't see this touching the nav bar twice behaviour that you mention. Perhaps something else in your code is causing this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to react to a tap on the navigation bar? Save a reference to the active Popover and dismiss it by calling a method when the navigation bar receives a tap.

Comment: This is pretty much what I sought. Thanks for reminding me of this!